# Shift cipher loop function

Tags: powershell, shift, caesar-cipher

I would like to get some assitance for modifying this code to make it loop decryption function to output the encrypted messsages from keys (1-26) . what would we the easiest method to do so ? Another ForEach loop?

```
$key = Read-Host "Key value:" 
$msg = Read-Host "Enter Message"
Write-Host "Encrypted Message: " $msg -ForegroundColor "white"
$String = [char[]]$msg

$array = [char[]]$msg
foreach ($letter in $array)
{
    $nbr = [int[]][char]$letter
    if ($nbr -ge 65 -and $nbr -le 90) #UpperCase
    {
        [string]$Snbr = $nbr
        [int]$Nnbr = $Snbr 
        [int]$nkey = $key
        [int]$Enbr = $Nnbr - $nkey 
        if ($Enbr -gt 90) {$Enbr = $Enbr - 26}
        if ($Enbr -lt 65) {$Enbr = $Enbr + 26}
        [string]$ELetter = [char]$Enbr       
    }  

    if ($nbr -ge 97 -and $nbr -le 122) #LowerCase
    {
        [string]$Snbr = $nbr
        [int]$Nnbr = $Snbr 
        [int]$nkey = $key
        [int]$Enbr = $Nnbr - $nkey 
        if ($Enbr -gt 122) {$Enbr = $Enbr - 26}
        if ($Enbr -lt 97)  {$Enbr = $Enbr + 26}
        [string]$ELetter = [char]$Enbr       
    }    
    $EMsg = $EMsg + $ELetter    
}
Write-Host "PlainText: " $EMsg -ForegroundColor "white"
```

Comment: What's the problem? Wrong output, program crashes, something else?

Comment: Yes, wrong output. Now it displays only one decrypted message. I would need it to display all of the messages with all of the keys. Could you advice an easy method how it should be done? another ForEach loop?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe next *commented* code stub could help:

```
$String = [char[]]$msg
$EMsg = ''                     ### initialize `$EMsg` variable
$array = [char[]]$msg
foreach ($letter in $array)
{
    $ELetter = $letter         ### initialize `$ELetter` in advance for case that `$letter`
                               ### is not UpperCase nor LowerCase letter
    $nbr = [int[]][char]$letter
    if ($nbr -ge 65 -and $nbr -le 90) #UpperCase
```

…